# How to query between floating dates?

Tags: api, socrata, opendata

I am querying from this [dataset](https://data.brla.gov/Public-Safety/Baton-Rouge-Fire-Incidents/dakq-4sda). From the documentation I know there is a variable `disp_date` (floating_timestamp). From the [documentation](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/floating_timestamp.html#,) I think I should be able to use the `between ... and ...` on `disp_date`.

Suppose I want from 2016-01-01 to 2016-02-31. I tried the following:

```
https://data.brla.gov/resource/4w4d-4es6.json?disp_date between 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000 and 2016-02-01T00:00:00.000

{
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "Unrecognized arguments [disp_date between 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000 and 2016-02-01T00:00:00.000]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing `$where` statement at the beginning. Also, need some quotes around the dates. This worked for me:

`https://data.brla.gov/resource/4w4d-4es6.json?$where=disp_date between '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000' and '2016-02-01T00:00:00.000'`

With HTML encoding:

`https://data.brla.gov/resource/4w4d-4es6.json?$where=disp_date%20between%20%272016-01-01T00:00:00.000%27%20and%20%272016-02-01T00:00:00.000%27`